# For Loop Not Working?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
public class twoTimes 

{

     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {

        for ( int i=1; i<11; i++);
        {
            System.out.println("count is" + i); 
        }


      }
}
```

When I try to display i, java is not able to initialise the variable?

Comment: What does "not able to initialise the variable" mean?  What is the output that you see?

Answer (score 4):

Try getting rid of the ( ; ) at the end..

```
for ( int i=1; i<11; i++);
//-----------------------^^
// Remove that ;
```

Comment: thankyou, i remove the semicolon and it now seems to work. I still dont understand what the problem was?

Comment: @Michael Very innovative revision! Thanks

Comment: @user2037720 That result would be expected if the semicolon (;) was closing the `for` loop..

Comment: @user2037720 ... if it works after removing the semicolon.. then the **problem** _was_ the presence of the semicolon..

Comment: @user2037720 with the colon, you had a `for` statement with an empty block (the colon terminted the `for` statement, i.e. `for(x);` is equivalent to `for(x){}` ), and then a separate block statement. Without the colon, the block is executed as part of the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have ; at the end off your statement. It should be something like that:

```
public class twoTimes 
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        for ( int i=1; i<11; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("count is" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to remove the ";", but java doesnt let me run the code?

Comment: there was missing an { in my code. Sorry about that, try it again. it should work now =)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ; at the end of the for loop:

```
    for ( int i=1; i<11; i++);  <---------
{
    System.out.println("count is" + i); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a ; at the end of the for, it looks like the function/command ended. As specified in the previous answers, removing it will ensure your functionality.

```
public class twoTimes 
    {    
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {       
            for ( int i=1; i<11; i++)
                System.out.println("count is" + i);
            }
        }
    }
```

A semicolon (;) **always** indicates the point where a command would stop. The same thing happens if you create any method and put a ; after, won't work.

Answer (score 0):

public class twoTimes

{

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {

    for ( int i=1; i<11; i++)//; <----- Due to this it is not working
    {
        System.out.println("count is" + i); 
    }


  }
```

}